# index of array can be a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

first i wanna sorry for my english. ya, its very bad. so. lets go:
i've this obj:

```
estrutura = {  
 //tags 
 div : { 

      //subtags
      id:'page',
      classe:'container_12 ',

      conteudo: {
          esqueda: {
             //childSubTags
            id:'divMenuVertical',
            classe:'grid_3',
            conteudo : 'Ola, sou um grid de 3 colunas'
          },
            centro: {
            id:'divConteudo',
            classe:'grid_5',
            conteudo: 'ola, sou um grid de 5 colunas'
         },
          direita: {
            id:'divConteudo',
            classe:'grid_3',
            conteudo: 'Ola, sou um grid de 3 colunas'
          }
      }
  }
```

}

but when i try  do something like:

```
Array.isArray(estrutura[0])
```

returns the index isn't a array. why?  i'm trying make a recursive searching. someone could helpe me please?

Comment: Well `estrutura[0]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

it is not array because it is object. Everything in javascript are objects. You should create array like this: `var myArray = new Array();`